# ZFS on AWS /dev/ names when creating a pool

Tags: amazon-ec2, zfs

When creating ZFS pools on Linux it is recommended to avoid names like /dev/sdX, /dev/hdX because those mappings are not persistent and tend to change between restarts. So instead we use /dev/by-id or /dev/disk/by-path/

What I observed is that in AWS /dev/by-id is not populated. So what is the best approach for AWS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use /dev/by-path for Zpools in AWS. /dev/by-path is populated by default. As recommended in https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/wiki/faq#selecting-dev-names-when-creating-a-pool using /dev/by-path is one of the recommended approaches along with /dev/by-id

Comment: Note also that in EC2, the device /dev/sdX-style names (e.g. /dev/xvdX and other variants) should not change across restarts, since they are always "detected" consistently, by design -- you specify their ordinal position when attaching the volumes.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/device_naming.html